# Activity in ScreenSlidePageFragment?

Tags: java, android

I built a class called Dialer which extends Activity and implements OnClickListener. It load the dialer interface and contains all methods needed by it to función. However I don't understand how to incorporare that class to my view pager.

I know I can load the dialer .xml to my viewpager like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = null;

    if(mPageNumber==0) {
        rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_dialer, container, false);
    } else {
        rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_contacts, container, false);
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to use my Dialer class and it's metidos inside the viewpager. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not incorporate your Dialer "Activity" to the viewpager. Viewpager should use fragments in it. you need to convert your activity into fragment (very simple, you'll just have to alter some methods) and then use it in your viewpager.